# Ruby on Rails - Counting goals of a team in many matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, associations, counting, rails-models

I've got a **Match** model and a **Team** model.

I want to count how many goals a Team scores during the league (so I have to sum all the scores of that team, in both **home_matches** and **away_matches**).

How can I do that? What columns should I put into the **matches** and **teams** database tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd assume your `Match` model looks something like this:

```
belongs_to :home_team, class_name:"Team"
belongs_to :away_team, class_name:"Team"

attr_accessible :home_goal_count, :away_goal_count
```

If so, you could add a method to extract the number of goals:

```
def goal_count
    home_matches.sum(:home_goal_count) + away_matches.sum(:away_goal_count)
end
```

Since this could be expensive (especially if you do it often), you might just cache this value into the team model and use an `after_save` hook on the `Match` model (and, if matches ever get deleted, then an `after_destroy` hook as well):

```
after_save :update_team_goals

def update_team_goals
    home_team.update_attribute(:goal_count_cache, home_team.goal_count)
    away_team.update_attribute(:goal_count_cache, away_team.goal_count)
end
```

Since you want to do this for leagues, you probably want to add a `belongs_to :league` on the `Match` model, a league parameter to the `goal_count` method (and its query), and a `goal_count_cache_league` column if you want to cache the value (only cache the most recently changed with my suggested implementation, but tweak as needed).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try it as soon as possible. But, since I'm a rails newbie, I'd like to know what you mean when you talk about caching a value into a model. What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

You dont put that in any table. Theres a rule for databases: Dont ever store data in your database that could be calculated from other fields.

You can calcuate that easyly using this function:

```
def total_goals
  self.home_matches.collect(&:home_goals).inject(&:+)+self.away_matches.collect(&:away_goals).inject(&:+)
end
```

that should do it for you. If you want the mathes filtered for a league you can use a `scope` for that.

Comment: about that rule - wouldn't it be better to save information so it won't be recalculated each time?

Comment: I disagree that duplicating data is to be avoided at all costs.  Caching tables and columns are very useful.  In fact, `counter_cache` is built into ActiveRecord (an example of a caching column, not directly useful for this particular question).

Comment: yeah i don't really think that this qualifies as a rule for databases, what if you wanted to index that data?